# How to create an RSS feed out of favorite YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, rss

I want to publish the title of last uploaded videos of my favorite channels on my blog.

Is there any feature on YouTube for that?

Comment: You're favorite channel list is private data. There shouldn't be a public feed for it. You can try making a custom solution with the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Subscriptions_Feed).

Comment: Define 'favorite'?  Do you want a feed of the videos of all the channels you are subscribed to, or some subset?  If you want a subset, are you willing to use something like Pipes to merge to merge the individual channel feeds?